# Swift Date Conversion Not Same Time

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I am using the following function to convert a string into a date so that it can be converted to a different format using DateFormatter:

```
func changeDate(date1: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from:date1)!

    let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy / HH:mm zzz"
    let finaldate = dateFormatter2.string(from: date)

    return finaldate
}
```

I want to take a string that looks like `2017-08-29T11:49:19` and for it to display `08/29/2017 07:49 EDT` as a string.

Comment: If you have 4h differences from GMT, the date is the same.`2017-08-29 15:49:19 +0000` is GMT hour, with 0h0m diff. (4h not 2h difference)

Comment: Is your question how to convert an ISO8601 formatted date to your custom format `MMM-dd-yyyy / HH:mm zzz` ?

Comment: @Larme you mean 4h offset

Comment: @LeoDabus Sure. 4h, which corresponds to the EDT offset. I just couldn't do 14-11 correctly >_< I may have though 1pm instead of 11 am.

Comment: `EDT` is the same as  `UTC-0400`. The difference is correct. The output `2017-08-29 15:49:19 +0000` seems to be the result of a `print` statement. `print` shows `Date` objects always in `UTC`.

Comment: "The problem is between the first and second step should show the same date but they are different times" Wrong. `"2017-08-29 15:49:19 +0000"` and `"Aug-29-2017 / 11:49 EDT"` are the same time. The entire premise of the question is false.

Comment: This question is confusing. Your `finalDate` string properly matches your `date1` string. Your code is just fine. What's the problem besides your misunderstanding of printing the value of `date`?

Comment: I want to take `2017-08-29T11:49:19` and for it to display `08/29/2017 07:49 EDT`.

Comment: @Martheli It sounds like you want the original string to be treated as a UTC timestamp. Set the 1st date formatter's timezone to be UTC.

Comment: What can I do to improve the question. Trying to get the down votes changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` objects represent an absolute point in time. However, the string representations of `Date` objects generated using a `DateFormatter` do not represent an absolute point in time and hence they correspond to a specific time zone. When you use a `DateFormatter` without explicitly setting up a `TimeZone`, it defaults to the current timezone of the user.

If you want to use your input string as a UTC timestamp, you need to set up the `timeZone` of your `DateFormatter` to `UTC` when generating the `Date` object. You should leave the `timeZone` of your second `DateFormatter` on the user's `timeZone`, which is the default value.

```
func changeDate(date1: String) -> String {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from:date1) else return {""}

    let outputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    outputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy / HH:mm zzz"
    return outputDateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Comment: so how would I get a string representation to match the Date object?

Comment: There is no such thing as "a string representation to match the Date object". They don't "match". A Date is a date, not a string. A string is a string, not a Date. You can represent a Date as a string in hundreds of different ways, perhaps thousands.

Comment: I want to take `2017-08-29T11:49:19` and for it to display `08/29/2017 07:49 EDT`. The answer above displays `Aug-29-2017 / 11:49 EDT` still a few hours off.

Comment: *"When you use a DateFormatter without explicitly setting up a TimeZone, it defaults to GMT."* - Incorrect. It defaults to the user's current timezone.

Comment: @Martheli check now, changed the timeZone of the formatter to UTC for the first date and kept it EDT for the second date.

Comment: There is no need to set the timezone for the 2nd date formatter. That result should be in the user's current timezone.

Comment: The text in the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs is still full is mistakes. Please fix those as well.

Comment: Edited both paragraphs.